# How to bring other app window to front without activating it?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, z-order

I want to bring to front a window(from other application). Currently I'm using:

```
::SetWindowPos(hwnd, GetForegroundWindow(), 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_ASYNCWINDOWPOS | SWP_NOACTIVATE | SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOSIZE);
```

It works fine, but in some (unknown to me) cases, it makes the window always on top. According to MSDN, I should use `HWND_NOTOPMOST` in the place of `GetForegroundWindow()` but it doesn't work—the window stays under other (not always on top) windows.

How can I bring a window to the front without activating it?

Comment: The documentation says that `HWND_NOTOPMOST` "has no effect if the window is already a non-topmost window".

Comment: Some alternatives here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/916259/win32-bring-a-window-to-top

Comment: *None* of the proposed answers to the other question are a good solution. That entire question is just a mess. David's got your answer here.

Comment: I think I can't use that alternatives - all of them(I think) activate window, and I can't do this.

Comment: I've deleted my answer.  It doesn't work.  I don't think you can do this without taking over the input focus.  I think the window manager is designed to let users decide which window is on top rather than programs.

Comment: @Cody I just don't think it can be done, but I'm not sure enough to post that as an answer!

Comment: Ah, I missed the part of the question where it says a window from *another application*. Yeah, you can't do this for windows that live in another process.

Comment: Make it a topmost first with `HWND_TOPMOST`, and then a second call with `HWND_NOTOPMOST` to make it not so?

Comment: Thanks, looks like it works! :)
`::SetWindowPos(hwnd, HWND_TOPMOST,   0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_ASYNCWINDOWPOS | SWP_NOACTIVATE | SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOSIZE);
::SetWindowPos(hwnd, HWND_NOTOPMOST, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_ASYNCWINDOWPOS | SWP_NOACTIVATE | SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOSIZE);`

Comment: @Sath - You're welcome! Promoted the comment to an answer.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The other application's window can be made temporarily 'top-most' to bring it to front without activating it, first by specifying `HWND_TOPMOST` as 'hWndInsertAfter' in a `SetWindowPos` call and then by specifying `HWND_NOTOPMOST` in a second call (both calls with `SWP_NOACTIVATE` in 'uFlags'). If there's a risk of removing the top-most style of a window which is already top-most as a consequence of the operation, the `WS_EX_TOPMOST` ex-style can be tested beforehand with a call to `GetWindowLong[Ptr]`.

If there's a particular window that the other application's window need to be in front (as opposed to being in front of all windows), that window's owner can be set, again temporarily, to the window it needs to be in front. `GetWindowLong[Ptr]` with `GWL_HWNDPARENT` can be used to store the window's original owner, then a call to `SetWindowLong[Ptr]` to set the temporary owner, followed by a call to `SetWindowPos` with `HWND_TOP`, and then restoring the original owner with again `SetWindowLong[Ptr]`.

Comment: @David - Yes, tested on W7, e.g. I can bring a 'Notepad' window on top without activating it.