# How to set Word Application.Selection focused

Tags: c#, ms-word, vsto, office-interop, office-addins

I am building a Word VSTO Add-in. There I have a side drawer with some buttons on it. Now when I click on a button it inserts a predefined text in a document selection position. When it inserts the text I would like to bring back focus to the document itself.

How to do that?

My best try so far:

```
  Word.Selection currentSelection = Application.Selection;
  currentSelection.Text = ((Button)sender).Tag.ToString();
  Application.ActiveWindow.SetFocus();
  Application.ActiveWindow.Activate();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It makes sense to call the `Activate` method prior calling the `SetFocus` one:

```
Word.Selection currentSelection = Application.Selection;
currentSelection.Text = ((Button)sender).Tag.ToString();
Application.ActiveWindow.Activate();
Application.ActiveWindow.SetFocus();
```

Also you may find Windows API functions helpful for such scenarios. For example, the [SetForegroundWindow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setforegroundwindow) function which brings the thread that created the specified window into the foreground and activates the window. Keyboard input is directed to the window, and various visual cues are changed for the user. You may find the [Win32: Bring a window to top](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/916259/win32-bring-a-window-to-top) thread helpful.

Comment: I did both (and Dmitry's answer too) and it worked!

Answer (score 1):

Try `Application.ActiveDocument.Activate`.