# How to distribute a .NET application that uses a COM component?

Tags: c#, .net, com, activex

I have a C# application that I've been publishing via ClickOnce and now I want to use a COM component called "Microsoft Web Browser" because it gives me access to the underlying ActiveX of .NET's WebBrowser, which let me access the [Travel Log](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa768366%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) which I need for certain features.

I believe this component is on older systems or maybe older versions of IE in "C:\Windows\System32\shdocvw.dll". In my system is in "C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ieframe.dll". So this is a mess. How do am I supposed to distribute this application to random machines which all I know is that they have Windows XP min (I don't even know whether they are x32 or x64 processors)? Will it just magically work on their machines (if maybe my application is storing some kind of GUID of the COM component that is system independent instead of the dll path)?

By the way, I added this component as a toolbox item as per the answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6530083/cannot-add-c-windows-system32-shdocvw-dll-to-my-project) question I made before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK the component you're referring to is part of Windows. If I were you, I'd check each target OS (Windows XP SP3 x32, Windows Vista SP1 x32 and x64, Windows 7 SP1 x32 and x64, the server OS-es) whether they have this component installed and which version.
It is very likely after this check you will find out you do not have to distribute it yourself.

Comment: Well I'm pretty sure they do have it installed, but might be on different dlls or on different locations. Wouldn't this be a problem?

Comment: This will not be a problem, because COM components are referred using a set of registry entries. Create a quick test application that uses the Web Browser components and run it on your test systems. It should run fine on all systems.