# Handling COM events from IE

Tags: c#, .net, internet-explorer, com

I've got a requirement to monitor all instances of IE on a client PC and act on the browser navigating to certain pages and again act on them navigating away from those pages or closing the windows that hosted those pages.

I've written the following code that will list all open windows:

```
private static void ListWindows()
{
    SHDocVw.ShellWindows shellWindows = new ShellWindows();

    shellWindows.WindowRegistered += new DShellWindowsEvents_WindowRegisteredEventHandler(shellWindows_WindowRegistered);
    foreach (SHDocVw.IWebBrowser2 ie in shellWindows)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("ie.LocationURL: " + ie.LocationURL);
    }
}
```

Based in part on the [answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6530083/cannot-add-c-windows-system32-shdocvw-dll-to-my-project/8541532#8541532).

But I'd need to poll every second or so and run through that list every time if I were to use that.

I've also found some code that allows me to register for events as follows:

```
        SHDocVw.InternetExplorer IE = new SHDocVw.InternetExplorer();

        IE.BeforeNavigate2 += new DWebBrowserEvents2_BeforeNavigate2EventHandler(IE_BeforeNavigate2);
        IE.OnQuit += new DWebBrowserEvents2_OnQuitEventHandler(IE_OnQuit);
        IE.WindowClosing += new DWebBrowserEvents2_WindowClosingEventHandler(IE_WindowClosing);
```

But that seems to only work on windows that I've opened myself (Either that or I'm doing something wrong). Is there a way to register an event handler for any IE window on a desktop?

Comment: It is unclear why you switched from using the IE instance you retrieved from ShellWindows to creating your own with the *new* operator.

Comment: @OmarKooheji, why do you need to poll, can't you walk the list upon `WindowRegistered` event? Unrelated, keep in mind [the subtle threading behavior](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18458398/1768303) of out-of-proc event handlers. Might not be an issue for a console app, but still.

Comment: Your problem seems a perfect fit for a Browser Helper Object (BHO).