# Close single tab of IExplore in C#

Tags: c#-4.0

I am stuck in a problem, i.e. How to close a single particular tab in Internet Explorer.

I can use ShDocvW.dll to solve this problem, but I am just wondering is there any other alternate solution for this problem, I have to do this in OpenSpan Technology based on .net and there I am unable to add the reference of ShDocvW.dll in my project it is throwing an error message as- "Invalid Project reference file".

Thanks In-Advance !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have you tried "Microsoft internet Controls" from the COM tab. See reference link below.

[Cannot add "C:\Windows\System32\shdocvw.dll" to my project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6530083/cannot-add-c-windows-system32-shdocvw-dll-to-my-project)