# Check if Internet Page is opened in Internet Explorer

Tags: c#

is there a way to look up if there is a running IExplore.exe process with a specified uri opened in c#?

Best regards

Comment: what do you want to achieve? What if I opened that url with Chrome or Safari, Opera or FireFox ?

Comment: It is save that it is accessed via iexplore

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4173982/c-sharp-how-to-get-current-url-from-the-ie

Comment: I found this, might help start you off.. http://support.microsoft.com/?id=176792

Comment: Here is another post which covers your issue quite well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4173982/c-sharp-how-to-get-current-url-from-the-ie