# How get opened browser html coded with c#

Tags: c#, html, browser, windows

i was working on a little application using with webbrowser control inside her body.
you can access html codes in below situations :

1. **WebBrowser**
2. **HttpWebResponce** Of A Specific URL

i really want to learn how can i access html codes of opened browsers in my machine.

> FireFox - IE - Chrome

we can read their titles, so there should be a way to read their htmls codes.
what is the solution?

**My Goal :**
there a web site and there is a timer (hour : minute : second) in that web site.
i need to read that timer every second and set it to my local machine.
my local machine time should be exactly like that web site time.
but using with `WebBrowseror` or `HttpWebResponce` i losed 2 3 seconds and seconds are very important for me.

Comment: Try the `DocumentText` Property of your webbrowser object

Comment: For IE I think you should read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4173982/c-sharp-how-to-get-current-url-from-the-ie

Comment: To get Firefox url you can use this link http://grafanimasyon.blogspot.it/2012/10/c-ile-firefoxtan-adresleri-almak.html, maybe there's a way to ask html in place of url...

Comment: @RononDex -> Opened Browsers in windows - not webbrowser control...