# Syncing Internet Explorer toolbar (band object) across multiple tabs

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, tabs, toolbar

There is a similar question like mine from 2009 with no answers.
Here is that post:  [Multiple tabs in IE7 with one instance of the toolbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/983129/multiple-tabs-in-ie-with-one-instance-of-the-toolbar)

My question: Using banding objects in C# to create an IE toolbar, can we make it so there is only one instance of the toolbar running for all tabs?  Is there a work-around?

I am wondering if there is now a way to do this while still using band objects in c#.  If not, could someone suggest a work-around (or a resource for a work-around)?  I am doing development on an IE toolbar that requires a user to log in to our web service, unfortunately, when they open a new tab THEY HAVE TO LOG IN AGAIN!  We really want to get rid of this, so any help you could give me would be great.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep a global variable for LogIn ..or LogIn_SessionId. So if that variable is populated, no need to show the dialog again. Once the dll is loaded in memory , global data would remain there, even how many times dll load/unload is called.