# Application that can open program in full screen?

Tags: c#, winapi, process, fullscreen

I need to make an application that starts new program (ex. notepad) in fullscreen mode. Can I do that in c#?

I'd appreciate a code sample.Thanks:)

Answer (score 14):

You can use [`Process.Start`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0w4h05yb.aspx) with a [`ProcessStartInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.aspx) object which has a [`WindowStyle`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.windowstyle.aspx) property. You can set that property so that the window starts maximized.

Adapted from the example at `Process.Start`:

```
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("notepad.exe");
startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Maximized;
Process.Start(startInfo);
```

If the process is already running, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4566632/maximize-another-process-window-in-net)

Comment: That's maximised, not full screen.  Not sure if sprintoflinz actually meant maximised, but he did say fullscreen.

Comment: I doubt there's a way to make external processes fullscreen... There technically isn't even a way to do that for C# Windows forms. You have to use a combination of different things to "fake it".

Comment: @Michael: What's the difference between "maximized" and "full screen"? That the taskbar is hidden?

Comment: Full screen hides the task bar and window chrome.  Think full screen for first person shooters.

Answer (score 1):

`F11` key is most often used to enter and exit fullscreen mode, so after program starts, you can call User32.SendInput WinApi (use PInvoke.User32 from Nuget).

```
   static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        StartProcess(_Config.FileName, _Config.Args);
        await Task.Delay(_Config.Delay);
        SendKey_F11();
    }

    static void StartProcess(string fileName, string args)
    {
        new Process()
        {
            StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo()
            {
                FileName = fileName,
                Arguments = args
            }
        }
        .Start();
    }

    static void SendKey_F11()
    {
        PInvoke.User32.INPUT inp = new PInvoke.User32.INPUT();
        inp.type = PInvoke.User32.InputType.INPUT_KEYBOARD;
        inp.Inputs.ki.wVk = PInvoke.User32.VirtualKey.VK_F11;
        inp.Inputs.ki.wScan = PInvoke.User32.ScanCode.F11;

        PInvoke.User32.SendInput(1, new[] { inp }, 40);
    }
```

In the same way you can call any other hotkey command to enter fullscreen mode.