# how to call single instance class from App.xaml.cs

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have an application that should only be allowed to run one instance per user session. If the user clicks to launch the application again, I want to bring the one already to focus.
I followed the steps in this tutorial [WPF Single Instance Application](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/84270/WPF-Single-Instance-Application)

and the steps in this tutorial is :

Step 1: Add the file [SingleInstance.cs](http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2004/08/20/the-misunderstood-mutex.aspx) to your project.

Step 2: Add a reference to your project: System.Runtime.Remoting.

Step 3: Have your application class implement ISingleInstanceApp (defined in SingleInstance.cs).

The only method in this interface is:

Hide   Copy Code
bool SignalExternalCommandLineArgs(IList args)
This method is called when a second instance of your application tries to run. It has an args parameter which is the same as the command line arguments passed to the second instance.

Step 4: Define your own Main function that uses the single instance class.

Your App class should now be similar to this:

Hide   Copy Code
/// 

Step 5: Set new main entry point.

Select Project Properties –> Application and set “Startup object” to your App class name instead of “(Not Set)”.

Step 6: Cancel the default WPF main function.

Right click on App.xaml, Properties, set Build Action to "Page" instead of "Application Definition".

I stick at step 4 I don't know how to define my own Main function that uses the single instance class?
anyone help me please, thanks

Comment: Have a look at [My Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38473277/wpf-single-instance-window-clickonce-pass-arguments) and ignore the Parameter-Part

Answer (score 0):

Okay it is so easy add this method to your App.xaml.cs file in the App Class:

```
[STAThread]    
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    if (SingleInstance<App>.InitializeAsFirstInstance("MyApp"))
    {
        var app = new App();
        app.InitializeComponent();
        app.Run();
        // Allow single instance code to perform cleanup operations
        SingleInstance<App>.Cleanup();
    }
}
```

Comment: GRADApp didn't accept and there is a red line under it why?

Comment: it became in the blue color but still had a red line under it and the error is saying "the type of MyApp.App cannot be use as type parameter TApplication is the generic type or method Microsoft.Shell.SingleInstance<TApplication> there is no implicit reference conversion from MyApp.App to Microsoft.Shell.SingleInstanceApp

Answer (score -1):

```
using System.Threading;

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
static extern bool SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);

/// <summary>
/// The main entry point for the application.
/// </summary>
[STAThread]
static void Main()
{
   bool createdNew = true;
   using (Mutex mutex = new Mutex(true, "MyApplicationName", out createdNew))
   {
      if (createdNew)
      {
         Application.EnableVisualStyles();
         Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
         Application.Run(new MainForm());
      }
      else
      {
         Process current = Process.GetCurrentProcess();
         foreach (Process process in Process.GetProcessesByName(current.ProcessName))
         {
            if (process.Id != current.Id)
            {
               SetForegroundWindow(process.MainWindowHandle);
               break;
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Application.Run(new MainWindow()); didn't accept in my code and the error is ===> the best overloaded method for System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run (System.Windows.Forms.ApplicationContext has same invalid arguments

Comment: This is an WinForms Solution. Not really helpful on WPF