# How to identify a winforms button control that has no AutomationId?

Tags: c#, winforms, ui-automation

I've been tasked to find out how to implement UI automation for desktop apps with appium-dotnet-driver. I've successfully managed to use the windows calculator app for UI unit testing.

That being said, having a lot of trouble with my company's winforms app because some elements either don't have an AutomationId or it changes every time something is clicked on the program.

Is there an easy way to define the AutomationId for a control type (i.e. Button)?

Comment: Can you identify the controls by name? That's also an option.

Comment: Some (which I need) have empty strings as names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved by setting the Name property of relevant controls. AutomationId is automatically inferred from `Name` or `Text` properties. Hope it helps someone.

Comment: Another interesting feature is the [Control.AccessibilityObject](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.accessibilityobject). It provide useful properties. It does not include the Control's Handle, though. You need to cast the `[Control].AccessibilityObject` to [Control.ControlAccessibleObject](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.controlaccessibleobject) for that: `IntPtr ctlHandle = ([Control].AccessibilityObject as Control.ControlAccessibleObject).Handle;`

Comment: Sample code here: [Run event when any Form loads](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55960110/7444103).

Comment: Could you explain how that is relevant to my question? After looking at your example it's not immediately clear. Thanks!

Comment: *How to identify a winforms button control that has no AutomationId?*. Using its Handle. Or other properties: `KeyboardShortcut`, `Parent` `Bounds` etc. It also allows to call directly the DefaultAction without `InvokePattern`.