# Show (restore window) app instead open other instance in Windows Forms

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winforms, desktop-application

I have an app in Windows Forms, written in C# (.Net 4.7.2) that, when minimized, goes to the system tray.
The requirement is that when the user clicks on the desktop shortcut again, if the application is already running hidden in the tray, the screen should be restored instead of opening a new instance of the same application.
I know that this behavior is common in several applications, but I still haven't found a way to do this in Windows Forms.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use Mutex. There are many examples.

Comment: Sounds very much like [this posted problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50552592/run-the-current-application-as-single-instance-and-show-the-previous-instance)

Comment: so, do you think you can solve your problem with Jimis answer? then I would close this question as a duplicate

Comment: I tried to implement the solution proposed by Jimis, however, when the application is already running and both open again nothing happens ...

Comment: This is built into VB.Net, which you can use from C#.  See [here](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12890/Single-Instance-C-Application-for-NET-2-0) for an example...

Comment: Have you read this: [Single Instance Winforms application](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/the-weekly-source-code-31-single-instance-winforms-and-microsoftvisualbasicdll)