# Open/Show form with Mutex c#.net

Tags: c#, winforms

Is there a way to Open/Show the form if it already exists?
I have used Mutex to check if an instance of my app is open.

This is the code for my program.cs file.

```
 static void Main() {
            bool InstanceCount = false;

            using (Mutex m = new Mutex(true, "MyRunningApp", out InstanceCount)) {
                if (InstanceCount) {
                    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
                    Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
                    Application.Run(new Main());
                    m.ReleaseMutex();
                }

                else {
                    MessageBox.Show("Power Monitor is Already RUNNING, Please Check the System Tray.");
                }
            }
        }
```

I tried Show(); but it give me this error "The name 'show' does not exist in the current context".

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29260770/17034

Comment: It does work @HansPassant it shows me errors, Like MyApp does not contain a definition for start and no accessible method start