# How can make my application open just once in c#?

Tags: c#, .net

after I made a setup with my project and made it .exe in c#,i want to make my application(.exe) to open just once.Is there anyone who can help me with my problem ?thanks in advance.

I want to prevent my application from opening it again.

Comment: check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/184084/how-to-force-c-sharp-net-app-to-run-only-one-instance-in-windows

Comment: sorry, this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19147/what-is-the-correct-way-to-create-a-single-instance-application