# Multiple Process instances

Tags: c#, .net

Im trying to handle process exit (when user kill process from task manager) as below. But when I open the exe it opens multiple instances of same EXE.

```
    Process myProcess = null;
    String fileName = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.FileName;

    myProcess.StartInfo.FileName = fileName;
    myProcess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
    myProcess.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
    myProcess.Exited += new EventHandler(myProcess_Exited);
    myProcess.Start();
    Application.Run(new launchAuthentication());


private static void myProcess_Exited(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    log.Info("myProcess_Exited");
}
```

How to prevent it?

Comment: So whenever your process is run it starts another instance of itself, which then starts another instance of itself, which then... can you see where the problem is already? Did you just manually write a fork bomb?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the correct way to create a single-instance application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19147/what-is-the-correct-way-to-create-a-single-instance-application)

Comment: Also dupplicated is "[How to force C# .net app to run only one instance in Windows?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/184084/how-to-force-c-sharp-net-app-to-run-only-one-instance-in-windows)"

Answer (score 0):

it's just a loop, you tell your process "start myProcess, then it starts myProcess myProcess, which starts myProcess .."