# Open the file with the associated application if there is an app opened?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, desktop, file-association

Open the file with the associated application if there is an app opened, bring it to the frontend, and open the file.

I wrote an app associated with specified file extensions. Double click the extension file and launch the app through registry

```sh
# location HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\MyApp.Bif\shell\open\command

"C:\Users\alpha\AppData\Roaming\MyCompany\MyApp.exe" "%1"
```

Now I hope the file can be opened by an opened application. Then bring the app to the front end and be focused.

The only way I thought is:

1. open a new app.
2. check is there any opened app?
3. if no, open the file.
4. if yes, **notify it** to open the file, close itself.

- ***notify it***: tcp? namedpipe?

There is a common function, is there any direct method?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It'd be helpful if you tagged the question with what kind of application `MyApp.exe` is ([tag:console-application], [tag:WinForms], [tag:WPF], etc.).  It sounds like you want it to be a [single-instance application](https://stackoverflow.com/q/184084/150605).

Comment: It's going to be difficult to programmatically determine "is this file already open by a running application.".   I think you want to just invoke [ShellExecute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shellapi/nf-shellapi-shellexecutew) on the file. Most apps have logic to bring themselves to the foreground if already running.  Just rely on that to work.